# Creating polygon in mobile using Google Map 3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3

I want to create a map in mobile app and then user has the ability to mark boundry i.e polygon on it. So is it possible to make like that aor is there any library available
Here is an [example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/drawing-tools)  in which user create polygon on `click event` how can i manage it in mobile app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo in a jQM page: **http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8TK6a/1/**

Inside the standard page layout is a div for the map:  `<div id="map"></div>` with this CSS;

```
#map{
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
   border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Then in code:

```
var map;
var elevator;
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 6,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.231719,-113.030911),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map($('#map')[0], myOptions);
var dm = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({map: map, polygonOptions: {editable:true,fillColor:'#777777',strokeColor:'#595959',strokeWeight:2}});
```

UPDATE: added polygonOptions editable:true so you can see dots at each vertex.

Comment: Hi
I tried this in web and mobile in web it shows a line during creating polygon after first click until it completes mobile it's not showing.
Is it posible to show a line (something like movable line)

Comment: I just visited the fiddle result (http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8TK6a/1/embedded/result/) on an android Nexus 7 and my iphone. In both cases I drew a polygon just fine. Double-tap for the first point, then tap other points finally tapping the first point to close the polygon.